# OpenGL/GLFW depth test doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Edit: Bandicam was causing the depth test to be reset for some reason. I suppose I have to call the glEnable function every time I draw to prevent applications such as Bandicam from interfering.

My textured cube spins and displays perfectly if I call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` in the render function. If I enable depth testing in the initialization function as the tutorial I am following says to do, faces overlap incorrectly as if depth testing hadn't been enabled. Please let me know what I have done incorrectly. Thank you.

Comment: The most logical explanation would be that your code, or something called by your code, disables the depth test. Is there a `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` anywhere in your code base? For example in `ilInit()`, or 'Oreg::Core::update()`?

Comment: @Reto Koradi None of the functions I've written have glDisable in them. If I call the enable function after initializing the DevIL library, the results are the same.